# Is this product of two product factorizations correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant, factoring, products

I am working on an induction proof and would like to know whether this product equality is true:

$$\big (\prod_{i=2}^n (\lambda_i-\lambda_1) \prod_{n\ge i > j \ge 1}(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)\big )$$

$$= \prod_{n\ge i > j \ge 1}(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)$$

The last product is what I need to end up with, so if the equality is true, then I have arrived at the answer.  It seems ok to me, but I just wanted to be sure, since accounting for the indices is a bit tricky.

Thanks,

Comment: Try testing your equality with $n= 2$. I suspect you want $j > 1$ rather than $j \ge 1$ in the constraint for the second product.

Comment: Hi @RobArthan, nope, I'd want $j \ge 1$.  I am computing the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix.  The first product on the left I got from pulling out factors of order 1 from each column.  Then, I have a 1 on the upper-left corner, and zeroes on the rest of the first column and first row.  So, the determinant is now just reduced to, by Laplace expansion, 1*det(size(n-1) matrix), from which I can use the induction hypothesis, which is the *second* product on the L.H.S. ... hmm...

Comment: Oo, perhaps I need to substract 1 from the indices in the second product, since we only go up to (n-1) for the induction hypothesis.  Would that fix it all @RobArthan?  Thanks :-)

Comment: I think it might!

Comment: hmmmm @RobArthan ... i hope so ... brb...